# App crash during displaying remote notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, toast, crash

I am trying to display a banner using [Toast](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast) if the app receives a notification while its on the foreground.

The simple case works fine without any problems..

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UIView *parentView = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view;
    [parentView makeToast:@"toast"];
}
```

however when I try to show a custom view of my own, I get a bad `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on the `showToast` method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UIView *bannerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.topController.view.frame.size.width, 80)];
    UIView *parentView = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view;
    bannerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [parentView showToast: bannerView duration:3.0 position:CSToastPositionTop completion:nil];
}
```

Is `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` method a dangerous place to program this type of behavior? Having a strong reference to parentView doesn't seem to work as well, how can I determine which object is getting overreleased?

Comment: Is the `parentView` nil by any chance when you're calling `showToast` on it? Btw, why are you trying to get the `rootViewController`? Shouldn't you get the currently visible controller?

Comment: I dont think parent view is nil, the first example would fail as well, right? My root view is a navigationController so i think its safe?

Comment: Does `makeToast` work instead of `showToast` where you're getting the bad access?

Comment: How about using the `makeToast:duration:position` method instead of that `showToast`? Or you're using `showToast` because you need to set the background color? Have you tried a strong reference to `bannerView`?

Comment: so my question is simplified and I intend to show a really custom view.. I get the bad access error when I use makeToast:duration:position:style as well. I suspect its something internal in the Toast library.. I might just use another library or build it myself..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103774/discussion-between-alex-and-gorkem-yurtseven).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting parent view, which is visible right now, You can directly show toast on `appdelegate` window, which is on top layer of all the view.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{


    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
       [self.window makeToast:@"This is a piece of toast."];
    }
}
```

Comment: may window is nil at that time.. you can check it by breakpoint.